# Why do a certain directory content's permissions change when shutting down computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, permissions

I'm using the `sudo chmod -R 775 /dev` command via the terminal for development purposes, but, every time my computer shuts down, all of the directory's contents revert to how they were before the command.

I need to do this every time I boot my computer and it has become tiresome. Is there a fix to this that will allow the `/dev` folder's contents to permanently change permission settings?

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

/dev is not a real directory.
It's used by the kernel:   http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html

What this means is that it's rebuilt/changed every time your computer starts (and as it is running as a matter of fact). It's more like a mapping than a real dir.

Comment: So is there a way to change the permissions of these files every time they are rebuilt? A script, perhaps, that runs every time the computer boots? Is this what you would reccomend.

Comment: a script that runs at boot would help I guess. If you really want to do this I would recommend a cron that periodically resets the permissions. I would like to understand why you want to do this in the first place, but yeah, a cron would probably be the way to go.

Comment: So I'm developing an application that needs to connect with some external devices (arduino, LED board, and a camera), but these devices lack the ability to interface with my computer under their current permissions. So the only way I know of for allowing them to communicate with the application is to change the permission of the contents within the '/dev' folder.